# Android Button Alignment using Table Layout

Tags: android, button, android-tablelayout

I was trying three buttons to keep aligned using Table Row, but the middle one remains in air, any idea what am I missing?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/abc" android:text="ABC"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/def" android:text="DEF"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ghi" android:text="GHI"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
```

Couldn't attach snapshot but giving some hint below by drawing. The first and third button are perfect but middle one remains little bit up from bottom. Any idea ?

```
**********************************
*                                *
*   ABC        DEF        GHI    * 
*          ************          *
************          ************
```

Comment: Couldn't add snapshot as my profile lacks some credentials

Comment: I copied this code in my demo layout. It is displaying three buttons at bottom in single line. What is the problem? Can you please share any dummy screen for that?

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup" android:text="ABC"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/downloadcerti" android:text="DEF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsbutton" android:text="GHI"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Please suggest correct replies, your reply itself contains errors. You cannot define "String" to android:height. Also i tried android:layout_height instead of android:height which even won't work

Comment: @Krishna, as i am not allowed to share screenshot because i lack some credentials to post images in stackoverflow, i have draw same scenario above. The middle button remains in air

Comment: I got the answer. There is no problem in code. I was setting color to other two buttons in class as button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); due to which third button was appearing different. You can also use my code to set three buttons in single line using TableLayout

Comment: sorry guys there were a typo !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/abc"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/def"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:text="DEF"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ghi"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:text="GHI"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```